# NodeJS on AWS EC2: Cannot load public/images folder

Tags: node.js, image, amazon-web-services

I'm developing a NodeJS app and it looks good on my localhost so I decided to deploy it on AWS EC2.

I followed AWS instruction to deploy my NodeJS app on AWS EC2. When I started the server on EC2 by running node server.js, I found out that although javascript and css resources under public folder were loaded, all  images from public/images were not loaded and the images folder was missing under Chrome developer tool > Sources. When running the app locally, all the images from public/images were loaded correctly. There is also a 500 Internal server error on the Chrome console.

Here is an example of my html for one of the images:

```
<img src="public/images/my_logo.png"></img>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe provide a link to the instructions you followed?

Comment: sorry, here is the link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It turns out this is an AWS permission issue. Somehow all images uploaded to EC2 have

```
-rw-------
```

permission. So I changed the permission to solve the 500 error.

```
chmod 744 my_logo.png
```

It's worth noting that only images uploaded to AWS have the above mod. Other files have the following mod which need not be changed

```
-rw-r--r--
```